# Page Templates with Form XObject in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm writing a PDF generation library and wanted to add the the ability to use other PDFs as templates. The specification notes a `TemplateInstantiated`property on pages with the alias of the template object should be all that is needed.

Here is a gist of the pdf content:

https://gist.github.com/tyre/89c12f8203181f078001

The template itself is stored [in object 16](https://gist.github.com/tyre/89c12f8203181f078001#file-pdf-L202) and the page in [object 19](https://gist.github.com/tyre/89c12f8203181f078001#file-pdf-L409).

`qpdf --check` reports the PDF as invalid:

```
WARNING: tmp/alpaca.pdf: file is damaged
WARNING: tmp/alpaca.pdf (file position 32089): xref not found
WARNING: tmp/alpaca.pdf: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table
checking tmp/alpaca.pdf
PDF Version: 1.7
File is not encrypted
File is not linearized
```

Comment: I downloaded your pdf gist. it indicates a xref at 32089 (as already your qpdf output indicates) but your cross reference table is not there at all. it looks like being at 48583 (unless the gist has treated the PDF as text). The entries of the table look wrong, too.

Comment: BTW, the transition `startxref 116 %%EOF  endstream endobj 17 0 obj` looks at least weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your PDF document is completely and utterly broken and that you have misunderstood a number of key concepts. You cannot simply incorporate a complete PDF file into another PDF file in the way you have done and expect that to work.

The template system you are referring to is intended to include "hidden" pages - not referenced in the pages tree in the PDF file - in the context of an interactive form document (or interactive document in general). That doesn't sound like what you are intending to do. And these pages need to be valid PDF pages. You can in other words not just include the original PDF document verbatim and expect the PDF reader to sort things out; you need to insert a syntactically correct PDF page object.

What you want to do is take the content of a document and apply that as a background to a document. This most commonly is done using XObjects. Pseudo-code for this could be:

- Open the original PDF document
- Open the "template" document
- Read the template document and copy all elements from the template page into a newly created XObject in the original PDF document.
- Modify the page contents of the pages in the original PDF document to paint the new XObject at the beginning of the page description of the existing pages.

It's important to note that again, you're not supposed to simply insert the template document into the stream for the newly created XObject. You will have to create a valid XObject that contains a properly formed resources dictionary referencing all resources needed by your XObject, and that contains the content stream from your template document.

Comment: Awesome! This makes a lot more sense. The specification is quite confusing around this. Back to the basics!

Comment: You can have a look at existing API allowing to use existing PDF as template (iText, go.applidok.com, ...).

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated in comments, the PDF presented by the OP is structurally defect, the cross reference table position and entries are wrong. Furthermore the transition from one PDF revision to a next update looks questionable. Essentially, therefore, the OP will have to provide a sample PDF which is at least syntactically correct.

That been said, though, the OP indicated he was

> writing a PDF generation library and wanted to add the the ability to use other PDFs as templates. The specification notes a TemplateInstantiatedproperty on pages with the alias of the template object should be all that is needed.

The Named Pages mechanism is not meant for something like that. Its main current use (if it is used at all) is in the context of spawning page templates by Acroform actions.

For using pages from other PDFs, one can simply copy them (and the referenced other objects) from the source PDF if they are to be used as separate pages as is; and if multiple templates are to be put onto a single target page, one can wrap the copied sources into form xobjects and include them in the target page.